RSpec Test issues: Error prohibited this user from being saved: Username can't be blank
I'm building a Ruby on Rails application from a Test Driven Development approach. I wrote a RSpec test which tests User authentication & Authorization based on their role. I used gems like Devise, Capybara, Launcy e.t.c  In my case, the User when trying to Sign-up gets a default role set to "client"
Here is the RSpec test:
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include EmailHelper, type: :feature
end

RSpec.feature 'UserAuths', type: :feature do

  scenario 'user signs up as a client' do
    visit new_user_registration_path

    fill_in 'First name', with: 'John'
    fill_in 'Last name', with: 'Doe'
    fill_in 'Contact number', with: '1234567890'
    fill_in 'Address', with: '123 Main St'
    fill_in 'Username', with: 'johndoe'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'john@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'password'

    click_button 'Sign up'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
    expect(User.count).to eq(1)
  end
end

and here is my User Model:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ROLES = %w[admin therapist client].freeze
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  enum role: { admin: 'admin', therapist: 'therapist', client: 'client' }, _suffix: true
  attribute :role, :string, default: 'client'

  ROLES.each do |name|
    define_method "#{name}?" do
      role == name
    end
  end
end

attribute :role, :string, default: 'client' sets any user trying to Sign-up with role "client" and it is saved in the database. In my schema I have the following:
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.1].define(version: 2024_04_05_195810) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "role"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "contact_number"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "gender"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
end

When I run the Rspec test I keep getting this error:
UserAuths user signs up as a client
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
       expected to find text "Welcome! You have signed up successfully." in "Sign up\n1 error prohibited this user from being saved:\nUsername can't be blank\nFirst name\nLast name\nContact number\nAddress\nUsername\nEmail\nPassword (6 characters minimum)\nPassword confirmation\nLog in\nLog in Other users Log in as Admin Log in as Therapist"
     # ./spec/features/user_auth_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Here is the content of my new.html.erb:
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>

 <% if resource.client? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
 <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path(role: 'client') %>
  <%= f.label :Other_Users %><br />
  <%= link_to 'Log in as Admin', new_user_session_path(role: 'admin') %>
  <%= link_to 'Log in as Therapist', new_user_session_path(role: 'therapist') %>
<% end %>

<%= debug(resource.client?) %>

and my Registration controller is like this as well:
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]


  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :contact_number, :username, :address, :gender, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role])
  end
end


I have tried debugging from the HTML page of the sign-up to no avail. I have also tried other solutions from StackOverflow speaking of this issue but none seems to be working for me.
The HTML markup shows that the username field exists but it's not being filled after using all manner of fill_in   and this:
if user_role == 'client'
  fill_in 'Username', with: 'johndoe'
end

as well as fill_in_field('Username', with: 'johndoe')   and fill_in_field_with_placeholder('Username', with: 'johndoe')
The Username field exists in the HTML markup of the Sign-up page so I don't know why Capybara is not filling it. Any pointers as to how I can solve this? By the way, I'm using Rails 7 and Ruby version 3.1.0.

The problem is most likely that the input is wrapped in <% if resource.client? %>  and it's not returning the value you're expecting. Capybara can't fill in inputs that don't actually exist. Also on a side note expect(User.count).to eq(1) is prone to false positives if you for example used let! instead of let somewhere in your spec and a user is present. If you want to reliably check if a record is created use the change matcher. expect { click_button 'Sign up' }.to change(User, :count).by(1).

I would write model tests to cover the roles and then refactor it by moving the default to the database layer and not duplicating what can be a simple enum definition. Read the docs for ActiveRecord::Enum and KISS.

Also you have <%= form_for @user do |f| %>  just wrapping a bunch of links. Nix this.

Thanks, Max, I will give your suggestion a try.

btw - I think enum will make the ? and ! methods automatically.  The suffix is applied to the end, so you should have user.client_role? already
